# What is the VB "Shadow" or C# "new" keyword Equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, c#, vb.net, shadow

When I want to define a new implementation of a non virtual method, then I could to use `new` keyword in C# or `shadow` keyword in VB. For example:

C# code:

```
public class Animal
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //Do some thing
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public new void MyMethod()
    {
        //Do some other thing
    }
}
```

VB code:

```
Public Class Animal
    Public Sub MyMethod()
        'Do some thing
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Cat
    Inherits Animal

    Public Shadows Sub MyMethod()
        'Do some other thing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, my question is:

What is the VB `Shadow` (or C# `new`) keyword equivalent in **Java** ?

Comment: Note that you're not *overriding* the method in this case, you're defining a new implementation starting at this point in the class hierarchy. That's different. Overriding has quite specific semantics, especially how calls to that method are handled on variables that are of a supertype. And shadowing a supertype's method implementation has different semantics.

Comment: @Joey I edit my question to new implementation instead override keyword. thanks for note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary answer to your question is probably "There is none." Details:

Java's methods are "virtual" (in C# terminology) by default; they can be overridden in subclasses. No special keyword is required on the original method. When defining the override, it's useful (but not *required*) to use the `@Override` annotation so that the compiler will warn you if you're not overriding when you think you are, and so people reading the code (and JavaDoc) know what you're doing.

E.g.:

```
class Parent {
    public void method() {
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void method() {
    }
}
```

Note that there's no special keyword on `method` in `Parent`.

If a Java method is marked `final` (non-virtual, the C# default), you can't override it at all. There is no equivalent to C#'s `new` in that context. E.g.:

```
class Parent {
    public final void method() {
    }
}
class Child extends Parent {
    @Override                   // <== Won't compile, you simply can't override
    public void method() {      // <== final methods at all (even if you added
                                // <== "final" to the declaration)
    }
}
```